# COM Adodb.Connection in PHP - Uknown Field name on field that definitely exists

Tags: php, ms-access, com

I am using PHP to query an Access database on an IIS server using the COM function. Everything is going great, I am pulling out data, deleting fields that match parameters, fantastic.

However, when I try to do an insert query I get the following:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft JET Database Engine
**Description:** The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: ''Kimlik''. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again.'

But I know the field exists, has anyone encountered a similar situation?

I did some tinkering, and I am now getting this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft JET Database Engine<br/><b>Description:</b> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''<span style=\"line-height: 115%; font-family: \'Verdana\',\'sans-serif\'; font-size: 7.5pt; mso-ansi-language: TR; mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri; mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-bidi-font-family: \'Times New Roman\'; mso-bidi-theme-font: mino'.'
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with the actual SQL being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused because I was enclosing the fields in quotes,something I had tried to fix another error.